# migrating from normal java to struts2

Tags: java, servlets, struts2

Currently I have a servlet `CsmServlet.java` which is getting called by the client side, here is the `web.xml` part

```
<servlet>
    <display-name>upload</display-name>
    <servlet-name>upload</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.abc.csm.web.CsmServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

which is perfect. Now I have to use struts 2 and re factor all of my code so what shall i use in my `struts.xml` to call `CsmServlet` class.

Here is my struts.xml, right now i am making a redirect to a another page

```
<struts>
<package name="default" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">
    <action name="showResult">
        <result>/csminfo.jsp</result>
    </action>

</package>
</struts>
```

I'll repeat my question,

1. What shall i add to my struts.xml to make a request to CsmServlet class
2. Do I require any changes in my web.inf?

My **Servlet** content

```
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
 throws ServletException, IOException {

PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
Map<String, String> requestParamter=getParamMap(req.getParameterMap());
RequestTransformer transformer = new RequestTransformer(req);

//(map and operation type) goes to CSMData
CSMData data = transformer.transform(requestParamter);

RequestHandler handler = new RequestHandler(req);
String result = handler.handle(data);

log.info(result);
out.println(result);

}
private Map<String,String> getParamMap(Map<String,String[]> params)
{
Map<String,String> paramsMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
for(Map.Entry<String,String[]> entry : params.entrySet())
{
paramsMap.put(entry.getKey(),entry.getValue()[0]);
}
return paramsMap;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Struts implements the MVC architecture, ideally you would not want to have your servlet doing the controlling part. You may want to copy the logic from your servlet to the Struts action.
In general, you would have two options:

1. Dont have servlets in you code (as
   controllers) and let the struts
   handle controlling. Copy the
   business logic from servlets (if
   any) into the actions of struts.
2. In case you dont want bigger changes, you could forward you request from Strut's action to the already created servlets.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have uploaded my servlet content, can you explain me what needs to be done w.r.t my servlet code?

Comment: Your servlet seems be doing business logic as well as rendering. As mentioned, you have two options. Option 2 is quite simple but not the best where in from struts you forward the request to your servlet.

Answer (score 1):

Struts has a front controller servlet that accepts all requests and passes them on to Action classes that do the work.

I think your servlet is out of a job.

It sounds like it should be an Action class that's called by the front controller when clients ask for it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have added my servlet code in my question, can you take a look and explain me a little about what should I do? I am new to struts2

Comment: Not likely; I'm on my way to work.  I won't have time right now.